# Global Menu stopped working in Nautilus

Tags: 12.04

The top menu for nautilus doesn't work any more...the
image in attach shows what happens when I click on the
'bookmark' button (this only happens with nautilus).

It wasn't like that a couple of days ago...i think it's
related to a recent update.

How can i bring my beloved top menu back?

[image: clicking the top menu bookmark menu]

## EDIT:

I solved it by restarting ubuntu....

Comment: That looks like a glitch in the Global Menu. The Nautilus menu has not disappeared, as it's clearly visible in the picture.

Comment: that seems to be the right diagnostic given that re-insalling nautilus didn't help. Do you know how to fix the global menu - nautilus connection (the global menu seems to work fine with the other apps)

Answer (score 1):

You could try to reinstall Nautilus.

Open up the terminal and type the following:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall nautilus
```

Comment: i did it but the problem is still here :(

Comment: What Ubuntu version are you using? 12.04, 12.10 or 13.04?